# Is come can be used only when you're in the place that you talking about

Tags: word-usage

I heard that **come** can be used only if speaker is in the place he's talking about.

But there are a song "Mama I'm coming home". And it seems like the speaker is not at his home at that moment.

Is this line incorrect or there is an exception from the rule?

Comment: Cambridge dictionary has this example "Is he coming to the movies with us?" So, I think that's not completely true. I mean what you heard.

Comment: @Cardinal, yes you're right. I found that **come** can also be used in case someone is going with the speaker:
"Come - to move or travel towards the speaker or with the speaker: "

It's covering your example, but I'm not sure if it's the case of the song line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where you can find a quite clear explanation of the usage scenarios for **come and go** https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/come-or-go

Basically it is the direction of travel (from the point of view of the speaker or the listner or place of interest of the conversation in case of third person) that matters the most:

- Go is suitable for the movement towards a place that is away from both the speaker and the listener(Moving/Going away).
- Come is suitable for the movement in the direction of place where the speaker 
  or the listener is(Comming towards)
- When a moment is related to the third person,the usage of come/go depends upon the location(source/destination), the on-going conversation is focused on.